# Sonatype Nexus - API - C# - Unable to upload file - 400 BadRequest

Tags: c#, nexus, nexus3

I am new to Nexus and I am trying to upload a file to a Nexus Repo. I have pulled the swagger endpoint and looked through the help documentation and everything seems to be correct, in fact it worked once prior to just stopping. I am using the following C# code to post my request to our local Nexus API instance and receiving the following error message in the response:

Status Code: BadRequest (400)

```
[
   {
    "id": "*",
    "message": "No assets found in upload"
  },
  {
    "id": "asset1",
    "message": "Unknown component field 'asset1'"
  },
  {
    "id": "asset1.filename",
    "message": "Unknown component field 'asset1.filename'"
  }
]
```

Here is my C# Code:

```
private bool InsertComponent()
        {
            //Local Variable Declaration
            var returnValue = false;
            var form = default(System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent);
            var response = default(System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage);
            var responseStr = string.Empty;
            var responseObj = default(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject);

            try
            {
                using (var Client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
                {
                    //Add the authorization token to the request header
                    Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "<Base64Creds>");

                    //Build Form Object
                    form = new System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent();
                    form.Add(new System.Net.Http.StringContent("/Website/Supplier/JoshTest"), "raw.directory");
                    form.Add(new System.Net.Http.StringContent("Josh.txt"), "raw.asset1.filename");

                    //Add the image to form
                    var Image = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"J:\Projects\Nexus Research\Josh.txt");
                    form.Add(new System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent(Image, 0, Image.Length), "raw.asset1");

                    //Post to the API
                    response = Client.PostAsync(this.NexusUrlBase + "/service/rest/v1/components?repository=repo-release-packages", form).Result;

                    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
                    {
                        //Get Server Response
                        responseStr = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseStr))
                        {
                            //Convert from raw json string into a JSON Object
                            responseObj = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(responseStr);

                            if (responseObj != null)
                            {

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Failed to insert image into digital media storage bucket. Empty Response Returned");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Get Server Response
                        responseStr = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseStr))
                        {
                            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"J:\Projects\Nexus Research\error.json", Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse(responseStr).ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            return returnValue;
        }
```

It did work once the other day and uploaded the text file without issue but then suddenly a few days later I started receiving the ba request error.

I have looked at the following documentation and everything appears to be correct, please help

- https://help.sonatype.com/en/components-api.html?_ga=2.168721320.803078142.1709802080-673424694.1707471758
- https://help.sonatype.com/en/components-api.html?_ga=2.168721320.803078142.1709802080-673424694.1707471758

Comment: `It did work once the other day and uploaded the text file without issue but then suddenly a few days later I started receiving the ba request error`. no, that is not how software development works. Things don't just stop working without changes being made.